# Bootstrap and Jquery Contradiction

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap Carousel and drop down menu in my navigation bar doesn't seem to work when i include my bootstrap.min.js before

Here is my code

```
<link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS & JS -->
```

However if include jquery.min.js before bootstrap.js my  tag in navigation bar doesn't work.Seems there is a contradiction between them

Comment: In order for bootstrap to work, jQuery must be included before bootstrap. Bootstrap won't work without jQuery added first

Answer (score 0):

Change the order. JQuery.js first, and then bootstrap.js. Order should be like this

```
<link href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**Note:** Usually `.js` files listed at the bottom of the html codes (inside `html` tag).

Comment: when i change the order  my navigation bar links dont work

Comment: have you checked console? is there any error message?

Comment: it is giving me a warning No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Niit-ECommerce/Styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Dispatcher' .In my style.css i have done some styling which is happening.

Comment: if it is very urgent need for you, then you can send me your code. i'm checking on my machine :)

Comment: i am not able to put my code it is too long. In my navbar i have various link one of them is <a href="AboutUs">About-us</a></li> .I have a dispatcher Servlet which sends request to my Home Controller @Controller
public class HomeController {
 
 @RequestMapping("/")
 public String Homepage()
 {
  return "index";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/AboutUs")
 public String AboutUs()
 {
  return "AboutUs";
 }

Comment: mhsjaber@gmail.com. send me here

Comment: `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

change your jquery

Comment: i've edited my answer. replace your code by this. hope this will work